# Android Studio Iguana: 'Build failed with 17 issues found' outdated dependencies? how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, android, gradle, plugins, apk

Today, I tried to manually export gdevelop project to apk using cordova cli and Android studio iguana.

My java jdk version is 21 and gradle version is 7.6.4.

Procedure I did:

1.) cordova platform add android@11
via cmd;
2.) build the apk in Android studio, but got these build failed error log:

'17 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 32, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
7. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 32, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
8. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
9. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-30.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
   of at least 31, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
10. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-30.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 33, for example 33.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
11. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-30.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 33, for example 33.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
12. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-30.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 33.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
13. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-30.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 33.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
14. Dependency 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-30.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 33.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
15. Dependency 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app is currently compiled against android-30.

    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
    of at least 31, for example 33.

    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
    allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
    targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
    minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
    on).
16. Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
    depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
    Android APIs.

    :app '

//

How to fix this? Sorry I am new to developing apps and I want to learn.

I want to try to build debug apk using cordova cli and android studio.

Comment: Read through the recommended actions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.